# Convert java.util.HashMap keys to vector in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` object that contains `key=>value` set which are both integers.

```
F = java.util.HashMap;
F.put(1, 123);
F.put(3, 432);
F.put(7, 31);
```

I need to extract keys to the vector. I access keys with:

```
F.keySet.toArray
```

It returns `Object`:

```
ans =

java.lang.Object[]:
    [1]
    [3]
    [7]
```

How to convert it to vector ?

```
[1 3 7]
```

Comment: what is a regular vector? can you explain please?

Comment: I mean standard vector like `[1 3 7]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try as following:

```
>> F = java.util.HashMap;
F.put(1, 123);
F.put(3, 432);
F.put(7, 31);
>> vec = cell2mat(F.keySet.toArray.cell)
vec =
     3
     7
     1
>> whos
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class                 Attributes

  F         1x1                    java.util.HashMap               
  ans       0x0                 0  double                          
  vec       3x1                24  double                          
  z         3x1                    java.lang.Object[]
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you looking for?

```
Vector V=new Vector();
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
V.add(ans[i]);
```

where `ans` is the Object[] that you have?